# jquery: print out hidden element

Tags: jquery, printing, element, hidden

i'm using the jQuery Print Element plugin for printing but i think it's a general css issue:

how can i print out a hidden element? (with css set to display:none;)

when trying, i'm gettin only a plain sheet. is there any solution?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As DN suggest, using a print stylesheet will work nicely.  On the print stylesheet, set your css rule to `#element {display:block}`.

I'm looking at the [jQuery.printElement Options](https://github.com/erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/wiki/jQuery.printElement-Options), and there is an option `overrideElementCSS`.  It seems to be just what you need. Here is the example code:

```
$("#element").printElement( 

            { 

            overrideElementCSS:[ 

        'thisWillBeTheCSSUsed.css', 

        { href:'thisWillBeTheCSSUsedAsWell.css',media:'print'}] 

            });
```

Replace `thisWillBeTheCSSUsedAsWell.css` with the path to your print stylesheet which has the `#element {display:block}` rule.

Answer (score 4):

Have you included a [print stylesheet](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml)?

Answer (score 1):

mind you that jQueryUI uses

```
{display:none !important;}
```

`!important` means you can't override it with the print stylesheet unless you also define `!important` (and I think you also have to link to your print stylesheet first in the page header before the jQuery stuff)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it could print only visible elements. In my case the following worked

```
<div id="to-be-printed" style="position:absolute;z-index:-9999;">
  <%= render :partial => "printed_version"%>
</div>
<div id="to_be_printed_cover" style="position:absolute;z-index:-8999;background-color:white;">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("div#to_be_printed_cover").css({ 
      height: $("div#to_be_printed").height(),
       width: $("div#to_be_printed").width(),
    });
  });
  </script>
</div>
```

I kept the main element(to be printed visible and absolute), and kept one on top of it to appear it as hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap your element in a div, and apply display: none; to that

```
        <div style="display: none;">
            <div id="printable-area">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> 
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```